# R failed to open xls on macOS

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to read a .xls file using the read_xls function, but always give me a "failed to open" message. I think there is an issue on my R or on my environment setup, because for every way I tried, I asked for a friend to do exactly the same, with the same file, in his machine. I tried running the code from both the R Shell and the RStudio, still gives me the error message.

```
library(readxl)
test <- read_xls("unb-dgp.xls", sheet=1, col_names = TRUE, col_types = NULL, skip=0)

Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet_i = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : 
  Failed to open unb-dgp.xls
```

My only guess of what might be causing a problem, is that I am running in a macOS.

Comment: Is the path to the file/filename correct?

Comment: Yes, if the file/path is incorrect the error message is: `Error: path does not exist:`

Comment: Does this happen with als xls files or only some particular ones?

Comment: Only some particular ones. But I sent this file to a friend and he opened without any problems

Comment: Are your friend and you using the same version of readxl?

Answer (score 1):

You may check this out https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/373. I also experienced the similar problem and I notice that not all columns' names are assigned. When I executed `readxl::read_xls(file)` on the different .xls file, it worked so, it is not the problem from this package and likely due to the file itself. Alternatively, trying `read.table` on the problem file also worked well.